# load-styles.php generates css rules. How are the generated styles determined and how can I alter them?

Tags: block-editor

I want to permit editors to edit pages using the block editor.

For the theme I'm working on, edits done with the block editor in the admin screen (the backend) are accurately reflected in the front.

The front end - the actual page - shows the edits in the way I want them to appear.
But the backend is loading some styles that interfere with the block editor.

The styles are being generated by load-styles.php.

I could probably find a way to force-load some over-riding styles, and use 'important!' rules. But this seems like a dirty solution.

I'd like to know if there's a conventional way to alter the output of load-styles.php.

How can I prevent it from loading the styles that are messing with the editor styles?